# is possible filter a TClientDataset using a insensitive case?

Tags: delphi

i need to filter a `TClientDataset`,  actually i'am using this code.

```
  if Value<>'' then
  begin
      ClientDataSet1.DisableControls;
      try
        ClientDataSet1.Filtered := False;
        ClientDataSet1.Filter   := 'Value LIKE ' + QuotedStr('%'+Value+'%');
        ClientDataSet1.Filtered := True;
      finally
        ClientDataSet1.EnableControls;
      end;
  end;
```

but the filter is working in case-sensitive  mode, is posible filter the record ignoring the case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you must use the [`FilterOptions`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSet.FilterOptions) property with the `foCaseInsensitive` value.

```
  ClientDataSet1.DisableControls;
  try
    ClientDataSet1.Filtered := False;
    ClientDataSet1.FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive];
    ClientDataSet1.Filter   := 'Value LIKE ' + QuotedStr('%'+Value+'%');
    ClientDataSet1.Filtered := True;
  finally
    ClientDataSet1.EnableControls;
  end;
```